# how to handle props in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to ReactJS and JavaScript framework in general. I am using a Django backend with an API that uses limit and offset.

I have created a function that can handle these paginations well:

```
handlePageClick(data) {
        this.setState({
            offset: Math.ceil((data-1) * this.state.limit),
            page: data},
            function(){
                console.log('/api/results?limit='+ this.state.limit +'&offset=' + this.state.offset)
            }
        )
    }
```

Also using the [react-js-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination) to make the pages very easily.

```
<Pagination
  activePage={this.props.page}
  itemsCountPerPage={this.props.limit}
  totalItemsCount={this.props.count}
  pageRangeDisplayed={5}
  onChange={this.handlePageClick}
/>
```

I tried to use componentWillUpdate until I learned that setState is Asynchronous.

```
componentWillUpdate (_, nextState){
        if (!isEqual(this.state.offset, nextState.offset)) {
            const pagination = {
                limit: this.state.limit,
                offset: this.state.offset,
            };
            this.props.getBy(pagination)
        }
    }
```

Then I use the recommended componentWillReceiveProps.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if (newProps.offset !== this.props.offset) {
            const pagination = {
                limit: this.props.limit,
                offset: this.props.offset,
            };
            this.props.getBy(pagination)
        }
    }
```

But now I can't find a way to update the variables to change the page.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, tbh. If you want to do stuff after the state has changed, put it in a function as second argument to `this.setState()`

Comment: What is `this.props.getBy`? My initial guess is that you need to call an API to get the pagination data, so either (a) a callback that calls `setState` with the API data should be passed to the API call, or (b) you can use `await/async` to fetch this data in-line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code into componentWillReceiveProps only. 
Now, on page change, If you're calling api to get further data then you can do that or you can change state through setState.

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if (newProps.offset !== this.props.offset) {
            const pagination = {
                limit: this.props.limit,
                offset: this.props.offset,
            };
            this.setState({limit:this.props.limit,offset: this.props.offset}, 
              () => {
                this.props.getBy(limit, offset);
              });
        }
    }
```